# parsing data in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing, select, oracle11g

I have a table keeps data something like this.

```
(ID:1683-->NAME:-->NORAH-->AGE:23-->HEIGHT:175)
```

However,I would like to select the data in the parsed form . How can I do that in oracle sql ?

```
ID    NAME    AGE   HEIGHT
1683  Norah   23    175
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show EXACT data format including table definition.  Your question is unclear?  Name,age,etc are all stored in one column??  FYI, if it is one big column, that is a bad design, and you may want to normalizing it.

Comment: Its design is like that unfortunately. I only have a select grant for this table and I want to eliminate "-->" and have 4 columns

Comment: IHMO PL/SQL is not right tool for this. It would be easier to maintain, is it was implemented as Java stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with test_data as
( select 'ID:1683-->NAME:-->NORAH-->AGE:23-->HEIGHT:175' data from dual )

select
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(data, 'ID\:'),'-->.*') ID,
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(data, 'ID.*NAME\:-->'),'-->.*') NAME,
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(data, '.*AGE\:'),'-->.*') AGE,
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(data, '.*HEIGHT\:'),'-->.*') HEIGHT
from test_data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot foe helping. You made my day :)

Answer (score -1):

Is your example a row in the table?

I think you can just

```
SELECT * FROM <table name> WHERE ID = 1683
```

Comment: I have a row that looks like ID:1683-->NAME:-->NORAH-->AGE:23-->HEIGHT:175. All i want to do that i want to convert it to more meaningful form.